# How do I fix PHP asking for a result instead of a boolean for mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on my chat app some more, and I got it inserting into MySQL fine. I apparently had the wrong engine. Anyways, it's wanting "mysqli_result" instead of "mysqli_fetch_assoc". I know this code is fine considering it works fine on another page.

I've tried retyping, copying the working code and putting my values, anything I could really think of... Here's my code

```
$query='mysqli_query'($con, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id ASC");
if ($query = true) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $username=$row["username"];
    $text=$row["text"];
    $time=date('G:i', strtotime($row["time"])); 

echo "<p>$time | $username: $text</p>";
}
```

I expected the code to work since I copied it from a working bit of code, but instead I got this, "
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/266/7895266/public_html/read.php on line 15
"

Comment: Because of the quotes around `'mysqli_query'`. This is a typographical error.

Comment: *"I expected the code to work since I copied it from a working bit of code"* - From where?

Comment: I've tried removing them, i still get the same result...

Comment: also, from my website. I can link it.

Comment: `if ($query = true)` that will always be considered as true; it's missing an `=` here. Best you check your connection and the query for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, remove the quotes around the function call.

```
// Incorrect syntax
$query='mysqli_query'($con, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id ASC");

// Correct
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id ASC");
```

But you also have another issue:

```
if ($query = true) {
```

Should be:

```
if ($query) {
```

or even better:

```
if ($query instanceof mysqli_result) {
```

Use comparison instead of assignment. By using an equals sign, you are making `$query` always evaluate to `true` and the **if** condition passes. The comparison should be checking for a non-falsy value -- specifically a mysqli_result object.

Comment: Whoa, thanks! That worked!